# Delphi -> Array of Byte to LongInt

Tags: delphi, move

I want to take 4 Bytes from

```
Source : Array[0..500] of Byte;
```

where

```
c : integer; // Start Point
```

to

```
v : LongInt;
```

but

```
Move(Source[c], v, 4);
```

gives me only 1 Byte back. Where is my fault?

Thanks again.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. BTW, I think Rudy's way is simpler: `PLongint(@Source[c])^`

Comment: Works fine for me exactly as you have shown it. Make sure your `c` value is correct.

Comment: Move works as so many have said. In case you didn't understand my answer to your other question, use Move to copy then entire array. You don't need to do it element by element.

Comment: And yes, if you really just want a single integer, then use a pointer cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This source works perfectly fine. It may however look like it returns only a byte if only the first byte (the one at index `c`) contains a value other than `0`.

This alternative, already suggested by Sertac Akyuz, works fine as well:

```
v := PLongInt(@Source[c])^;
```

Comment: @Michael only god knows? it's a simple pointer dereference over a cast over a pointer obtained via @ (at) operator!

Comment: And the other way works either, as I demonstrate in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13637317/255257)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt move is failing:

Try this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  source: array[0..500] of Byte;
  C: Integer;
  V: LongInt;
begin
  source[0] := $55;
  source[1] := $55;
  source[2] := $55;
  source[3] := $55;
  C := 0;
  Move(Source[C], V, SizeOf(V));
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(V));
end;
```

You will see the number 1431655765 ($55555555) in the message.